# Is there any way to construct an std::initializer_list from an unknown number of arguments?

Tags: c++

Hi there so im having some trouble battling a silly API. We have a function that is something along the lines of

```
void foo(std::initializer_list<T> access_list);
```

And what I want to do is take a run-time JSON array and use it to call this function. for example suppose the JSON was

```
data : [
  {
    x : 10,
    y : 20
  },
  {
    x : 30,
    y : 40
  },
  ...
]
```

Then id want to call `foo` with `foo({10,20,30,40})`.

The problem is, the JSON array can be any length so id have to construct the list in a loop (i.e. into a vector) and then call `foo` on the constructed list. This is not possible as std::initializer_list does not have any functions to modify it after its initialisation and has no way of converting from a container (such as vector/array etc.) to an std::initializer_list.

I understand this is a misuse of std::initializer_list but is there any way (macros welcome) to create such a list?

I think one approach might be to convert the std::vector into a parameter pack and then a macro on the parameter pack to form the std::initializer_list but im not exactly sure how that would look. Thanks :).

Comment: [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) objects can only be initialized at compile-time. There's no way to populate one at run-time.

Comment: `std::initializer_list` wraps a raw array.  The size of that array must be known at compile time.  If you want an array at run time, you want a `std::vector`

Comment: To construct a `std::initialize_list` at runtime you'd have to have your program output source code, invoke the compiler, and perhaps `exec` the compiled program (or perhaps dynamically load a DLL / Framework / Shared Object / Library).  Quite a bit of work for no gain and a huge performance hit, but not impossible.

Comment: XY problem perhaps....?

Comment: Btw, how many can the unknown amount be? Up to 10? 100?

Comment: "battling a silly API" The solution to that is to **file a ticket** (bug report, CR, ER, or whatever name your org uses).

Comment: What @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. is saying is important.  You shouldn't try to hack around like this unless you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are stuck with `void foo(std::initializer_list<T> access_list);` and you've populated a `vector<T>` with the data you'd like to supply to `foo<T>`, then you *could* build a runtime translator.

Caveats:

- The max number of elements you aim to support must be known at compile time.
- It's **terribly** slow to compile.
- It instantiates a function template 1½ times the number of elements in the `initializer_list<T>` you aim to support.
- It uses a binary search to find the correct overload in run-time. This is pretty quick though.

If you aim to support relatively few elements (I use 512 in my example) you may be able to live with this.

```cpp
namespace detail {
template<class Func, class T, size_t... Is>
decltype(auto) helper(Func&& f, const std::vector<T>& vec,
                      std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    if constexpr(sizeof...(Is) > 512) { // will throw a runtime exception
        throw std::runtime_error("more than 512 elements not supported");
    } else {
        if(sizeof...(Is) + 255 < vec.size())
            return helper(std::forward<Func>(f), vec,
                   std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is) + 256>{});
        if(sizeof...(Is) + 127 < vec.size())
            return helper(std::forward<Func>(f), vec,
                   std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is) + 128>{});
        if(sizeof...(Is) + 63 < vec.size())
            return helper(std::forward<Func>(f), vec,
                   std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is) + 64>{});
        if(sizeof...(Is) + 31 < vec.size())
            return helper(std::forward<Func>(f), vec,
                   std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is) + 32>{});
        if(sizeof...(Is) + 15 < vec.size())
            return helper(std::forward<Func>(f), vec,
                   std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is) + 16>{});
        if(sizeof...(Is) + 7 < vec.size())
            return helper(std::forward<Func>(f), vec,
                   std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is) + 8>{});
        if(sizeof...(Is) + 3 < vec.size())
            return helper(std::forward<Func>(f), vec,
                   std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is) + 4>{});
        if(sizeof...(Is) + 1 < vec.size())
            return helper(std::forward<Func>(f), vec,
                   std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is) + 2>{});
        if(sizeof...(Is) < vec.size())
            return helper(std::forward<Func>(f), vec,
                   std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is) + 1>{});

        // time to do the actual call:
        return f({vec[Is]...});
    }
}
} // namespace detail

template<class Func, class T>
decltype(auto) call(Func&& f, const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    return detail::helper(std::forward<Func>(f), vec,
                          std::make_index_sequence<0>{});
}
```

You'd then call `foo<T>` like so:

```cpp
std::vector<T> vec = ...;
call(foo<T>, vec);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7TMzEKo5c) - likely to time out during compilation - but works if you don't have such a limit.

Comment: That works great.  I didn't get any timeouts - at least not until I had more than 63 elements.  https://godbolt.org/z/8YWb939dh

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Nice! The actual number of elements in the `vector` doesn't matter so much. [512](https://godbolt.org/z/MW451xao4) works sometimes too. It's the instantiation of all the functions that are needed that takes most of the time. Actual running time  isn't so bad at all.